# Vectorizing An Equation

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking to fully vectorize a model I have for a mean reverting volatility process- aka the Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process.

I've followed along with the code here: http://nakamuraseminars.org/nsblog/2014/06/21/monte-carlo-in-python-an-example/ which has a similar, but different equation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def OU_estimation(M=100000, N=25, T=25, sigma=.1, mu=1, lambda_est=1, S0=1):
    dt = T/N # simulation time step 
    S = np.zeros((M,N+1))
    S[:,0] = S0
    for n in range(N):
        #Partially vectorized
        eps = np.random.normal(0, 1, (M))
        S[:,n+1] = S[:,n] + lambda_est*(mu - S[:,n])*dt + sigma*eps 
    df = pd.DataFrame(S)
    return df
```

Since the code is currently partially vectorized, it iterates over the number of steps taken, it is already pretty quick. I'm looking to see if it can be fully vectorized as more of a learning experience

Comment: BTW (M) == M, to build a tuple you'll need the coma (M,)

Comment: I don't follow. Can you better explain exactly what you're pointing out? Where do you think the comma needs to be placed?

Comment: @RikPoggi is (I think) referring to the `(M)` in the line beginning with `eps =...`. The function `.normal` expects a tuple there.  In order to make a length 1 tuple you need to put in a comma as shown: `(M,)`

Comment: Hmm- whether I have the comma present or not does not seem to change the output of the normal function. I added a print statement beneath, and the output from (M,) and (M) are indistinguishable.

Comment: If you're using Python 3 make sure you're not writing `print (M,)`. You need to write `print((M,))` as `print` is a function. Note also that many Python function that take tuples as arguments will assume an argument of any other type is meant to be a length 1 tuple containing that argument. However since `numpy.random.normal` doesn't seem to document this behaviour you probably shouldn't depend on it.

Comment: It doesn't look easily vectorizable in `N` direction to me. There is too much accumulative stuff and `S[:, n + 1]` depending on `S[:, n]` going on. Unless there is a weird closed form for this given `eps` is known for every step.

Comment: Agreed, if `n+1` depends on `n` it can't be vectorized. Vectorization depends on the elements being independent.

Comment: @Gabriel I came to that same conclusion, but wanted to see if I was correct. Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a vectorized way if you only calculate the last column:

```
def OU_lastcol(M=100000, N=25, T=25, sigma=.1, mu=1, lambda_est=1, S0=1):
    dt = T/N
    c = (1-lambda_est*dt)
    cv = c**np.arange(N)[::-1]
    R = np.random.normal(lambda_est*mu*dt, sigma, (M,N))
    SN = np.dot(R, cv) + S0*c**N
    return SN
```

This doesn't execute that much faster than the code with the loop using default arguments, so you can say using the loop in this case does little harm to performance. But for `N` much larger than `M` the loop overhead begins to show..